# Status of Unsaved Entities

Tags: entity-framework

Consider the following code.

```
var items = from i in context.Items
            select i;
var item = items.FirstOrDefault();
item.this = "that";
item.that = "this";

var items2 = from i in context.Items
             where i.this == "that"
             select i;
var data = items2.FirstOrDefault();

context.SaveChanges();
```

I'm trying to confirm that `items2` will not include my modifications to `item`. In other words, `items2`'s copy of `item` will not include the unsaved changes.

Comment: In light of your changes, I've added a followup comment below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried it? =)

By default, your objects are being tracked and cached by the context, so that the objects in your second query actually do reflect changes in the first.

You may want to call context.Items.AsNoTracking() on the one of your two "items" to get the behavior you want.

**Edit:**  Actually, this is a strange question.  I just noticed that your items2 hasn't even hit the database yet, since you haven't called ToList() or FirstorDefault().  It remains an IQueryable that will hit the database after your code snippet and will therefore contain the changed value.

HOWEVER, if you call ToList() on items2, you'll encounter the caching scenario I outlined above.

Comment: I see that you have added FirstorDefault() to your question.  Now you will run into the caching scenario I originally described.  There is no way around this unless you are willing to change the order of your code to call AsNoTracking() on your *first* set of items, then make changes on the entities in your second set.  (Or you can update your first set of items *after* calling AsNoTracking() on your second set of items).  After calling SaveChanges(), your first set of items will have their original values, since they are detached.  Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks. I'm not fully understanding all the details here, but I refactored my code so that this isn't an issue.

Comment: Well, OK, but this is a good opportunity to dig into some EF internals.  Are you using Code-first?

Comment: OK.  Well, would you find any value in some sample code relating to tracking, or is this question long dead?  =)

Comment: Thanks, but yeah, kind of busy with other stuff now.

Answer (score 1):

In case of "var item" your query is executed the moment you used FirstOrDefault(). But for var items2 the query is still not executed. Now in your case result of items2 will always be affected by the updates you have done in the first query.

Comment: It will include the unsaved changes. And its values may differ from the current values in the context. You are first firing the select query and saving in a local object and then you are updating the source.

Answer (score 0):

It will contain the modifications, only way to do is create a new context and query the new context.